# Finding elements repeating in many arrays in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have problem with comparing many arrays in one array. I need to get element which  exists in every array. It's look like this one:

```
array= [[11,12,13,14],[55,66,13],[13,15,17,22,34],[4,6,8,13]]
```

I need to get only: 13 - because its on every array, how to get it ?

Comment: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-26

Answer (score 5):

This should work

```
a.inject(:&)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use [`inject`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject) as mentioned by Nithin in another answer.

Another option is to use [`reduce`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/reduce):

```
ary = _
 => [
      [11, 12, 13, 14],
      [55, 66, 13],
      [13, 15, 17, 22, 34],
      [4, 6, 8, 13]
    ]

ary.reduce(:&)
 => [13]

# which is a short-hand for:
ary.reduce { |out, elem| out & elem }
 => [13]
```